# Correct way and location to initialise adapter

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-adapter, android-listfragment

I'm trying to setup a filter for my list view but I've come across these errors.

> Cannot resolve symbol 'myAdapter'

I know that `myAdapter` hasn't been initialised, but I don't know which of my classes I need to declare it in.

> error: method setOnQueryTextListener in class SearchView cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
>   found: android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
>   reason: actual argument android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener cannot be converted to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener by method invocation conversion

I know that `android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`cannot be converted to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` but I don't know what needs to change in my code. My app utilises the Support library. All help would be appreciated.

**VictoriaLineActivity.java**

```
public class VictoriaLineActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        //change background colour of action bar
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0098D4")));
        //change text colour of action bar
        actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>Victoria line</font>"));

        //enable and show action bar back button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        FragmentVictoriaLine newFragment = new FragmentVictoriaLine();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentVictoriaLine.java**

```
public class FragmentVictoriaLine extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements {

    private class Victoria {
        private CharSequence station;
        private CharSequence zone;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;
        private Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass;

        public Victoria(int stationResId, int zoneResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass, Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass) {
            this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.station = getResources().getString(stationResId);
            this.zone = getResources().getString(zoneResId);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return station.toString(); }
        public String getzone(){ return zone.toString(); }
    }

    private static Victoria[] mVictoria;

    /**
     * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
     * device.
     */
    public boolean mTwoPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_victoria_line, container, false);

        if (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }else{
            mTwoPane = false;
        }

        // Instantiate the list of stations.
        mVictoria = new Victoria[]{
                new Victoria(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCBankActivity.class, FragmentWCBank.class),
                new Victoria(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCWATActivity.class, FragmentWCWAT.class)

        };

        final ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_victoria);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mVictoria));
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        });

        return v;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_victoria_line, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
            {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
            {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return true;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView station;
            TextView zone;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Victoria[] mVictoria;

        public MyAdapter(Context contexts, Victoria[] samples) {
            this.mVictoria = samples;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mVictoria.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mVictoria[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.station = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                viewHolder.zone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.station.setText(mVictoria[position].station);
            viewHolder.zone.setText(mVictoria[position].getzone());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. It would help to define clearly the question and maybe narrow down the code posted (it is not so bad at this moment but it isn't probably all revelant to your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your errors pretty much tell you what you are doing wrong:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'myAdapter'

That is because you have not declared any variable called `myAdapter`

> error: method setOnQueryTextListener in class SearchView cannot be
>   applied to given types; required:
>   android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener found:
>   android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener reason: actual argument
>   android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener cannot be converted to
>   android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener by method
>   invocation conversion

Check your imports.  You need to use `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` but you are using the standard `SearchView`. This should be fixable by simply importing the correct package.

Edit:

You are using the wrong type of `OnQueryListener` you need to use the support version.

Edit 2:
Hopefully this will help you get started:

```
public class FragmentVictoriaLine extends Fragment {
    /**Declare other variables**/

    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    public FragmentVictoriaLine() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_victoria_line, container, false);

        //Tell the system to call onCreateOptinsMenu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        if (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        } else {
            mTwoPane = false;
        }

        mVictoria = new Victoria[]{
            new Victoria(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCBankActivity.class, FragmentWCBank.class),
            new Victoria(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCWATActivity.class, FragmentWCWAT.class)
        };

        //Declare your adapter here so you can access later
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mVictoria);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_victoria);
        //Set teh adapter here.
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_victoria_line, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
            {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                System.out.println("on text chnge text: "+newText);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
            {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                System.out.println("on query submit: "+query);
                return true;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);

    }

   /**....rest of your code*/
}
```

Edit 3:

Here is the full demo:
https://github.com/nak411/AndroidFilterListDemo

Comment: I think there is a bigger issue here with your set up.  You are accessing the search code in the activity but your adapter belongs in your fragment. You can actually access the search view from your fragment by calling [setHasOptionsMenu](/http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)) and then overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` in your fragment instead of your activity.

Comment: Please do not copy as is.  That was only a starting point for you.  System services are only accessed through context.  I'll update it but you'll probably need to go through a full tutorial to implement it correctly. [This one is a good one](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html)

Comment: Filter is not a widget.  Its something you have to implement please go through the tutorial.  Your adapter needs to implement `Filterable` for you to be able to call `getFilter()`

Comment: I actually meant the search view widget but will this work for a search view in the action bar?

Comment: Yes, because the fragment is defining the action menu by calling its own `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`

Comment: Viewed the link and it helped a bit. See updated code. However getMenuInflater, getSystemService and getComponentName are all in red
along with myAdapter as they are not resolved yet + I don't how to resolve them.

Comment: I'll try to create a sample on github and post it by tomorrow.

Comment: Doesn't work for two line list items. Please update code as necessary to facilitate this.

Comment: I won't have time to update this for at least a week.  Please ask a different question and point to this and maybe someone else can help you out.

Comment: Considering the time spent on creating that sample, it would've made a lot more sense and been more helpful to use the recycler view in the code.

Comment: Do you know how to alter the onQueryTextchange method in your code so that the list returns to its original state after clearing search?

Comment: The list already returns to its original state after search is cleared.

Comment: Not with my code for some reason - the OnQueryTextChange method needs changing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985218/list-view-not-returning-to-original-state-after-clearing-search/30985641#30985641