# List view not returning to original state after clearing search

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-listfragment

I'm trying to get my list to show all my items again whenever I cancel a search from my search view but for some strange reason, the list gets stuck with the results only from the previous search. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code and how to fix this? I believe something is wrong with the filter related code but I don't know what it is.

**FilterListFragment.java**

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<Item> mData;
    private List<Item> mFilteredData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter;

    public ItemListAdapter (List<Item> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mFilteredData = data;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mFilteredData.get(position).getItem();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(mData.get(position).getItem());
        holder.description.setText(mData.get(position).getItemDescription());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    /**
     * View holder
     */
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private TextView description;
    }

    /**
     * Filter for filtering list items
     */
    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

        /**
         * Invoked on a background thread.  This is where all the filter logic should go
         * @param constraint the constraint to filter on
         * @return the resulting list after applying the constraint
         */
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                results.count = mData.size();
                results.values = mData;
            } else {
                //Create a new list to filter on
                List<Item> resultList = new ArrayList<Item>();
                for (Item str : mData) {
                    if (str.getItem().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        resultList.add(str);
                    }
                }
                results.count = resultList.size();
                results.values = resultList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        /**
         * Runs on ui thread
         * @param constraint the constraint used for the result
         * @param results the results to display
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            if (results.count == 0) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                mFilteredData = (ArrayList<Item>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**List in normal state**
[image]

**List in filtered state**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are operating on the original data instead of filtered data.  You should maintain a reference to original data and use the filtered data for all other purposes.  So that the original data is displayed when search is cleared.

Replace all usages of `mData` with `mFilteredData` as below and only use the original data to generate the filtered data:

```
private List<String> mData;
private List<String> mFilteredData;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemFilter mFilter;

public ItemListAdapter (List<String> data, Context context) {
    mData = data;
    mFilteredData = data;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFilteredData.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mFilteredData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String strItem = mFilteredData.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mTvItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mTvItem.setText(strItem);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    }
    return mFilter;
}

/**
 * View holder
 */
static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView mTvItem;
}

/**
 * Filter for filtering list items
 */
private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

    /**
     * Invoked on a background thread.  This is where all the filter logic should go
     * @param constraint the constraint to filter on
     * @return the resulting list after applying the constraint
     */
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
            results.count = mData.size();
            results.values = mData;
        } else {
            //Create a new list to filter on
            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String str : mData) {
                if (str.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    resultList.add(str);
                }
            }
            results.count = resultList.size();
            results.values = resultList;
        }
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Runs on ui thread
     * @param constraint the constraint used for the result
     * @param results the results to display
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        if (results.count == 0) {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        } else {
            mFilteredData = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify my list view now has 2 lines for each item instead of 1. Would that code still work?

Comment: Yes if you need to match on the second item just add an  || condition when doing the comparison in `performFiltering()` to check against your second item.

Comment: Cool, however for some reason my list doesn't filter properly. e.g. When I type in 'europe' the item with the Europe title doesn't appear but instead Africa does. My **ItemListAdapter.java** has been updated for you to have another look at along with screenshots.

Comment: Your filter code seems fine. You need to use `filtered data` here in your    `getView()`  `holder.title.setText(mData.get(position).getItem());`
  `holder.description.setText(mData.get(position).getItemDescription());`

Comment: Brilliant - thanks. As seen in my screenshot none of the items contain the letter 'x'. I was just wondering is there anyway possible to make the list view invisible and show a label in the middle of the screen saying 'No results' if I type in a letter that is not in any of the item titles?

Comment: You can use the `result.count == 0` condition in `publishResult` to show that view.

Answer (score 1):

Add a log statement to onQueryTextChange() so you can see how your filter string is changing.  Note that SearchView does not call onQueryTextChange() with an empty string when the search view is closed.  You need to decide when you want the search string cleared, perhaps by adding a control for that, and do the clearing yourself.